# I'm a java developer struggling with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Guys i am very new to jQuery.
I have started using the auto complete feature.
What i want is while i click on an item provided by the auto complete the page should submit to another page.
I am using :

```
$().ready(function() {
        $("#name").autocomplete("contacts.jsp");
        $("#name").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
            if (data)
                $(this).parent().next().find("input").val(data[1]);
        });
        $("#name").setOptions({
        mustMatch : false,
        max: 8,
        onClick:selectItem,
        autoFill: false
        });
    });
```

And this gives me good data like :
Aditi Xaveir
Asif Garhi
etc for 'A'
Now what i want is on clicking Aditi Xaveir, the page should submit to Aditi
Xaveir's profile page.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this portion, do something like this:

```
$("#name").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
   if (data) {
     window.location.href = 'profile.jsp?Name=' + data[1];
     //Or if you're doing ID|Name in results, use the ID
     //window.location.href = 'profile.jsp?ID=' + data[0];
   }
});
```

I'm not sure how your profiles are setup, but this would take you to the profile with the given name via query string, etc....just however your urls are formed, use that scheme.